# Retorna o símbolo � em uma letra acentuada do banco de dados

Tags: php, html, phpmyadmin

O usuário pesquisa um nome na página, mais precisamente em um modal, quando o nome é retornado ele irá aparecer esse símbolo: � (se possuir acento). Mas no banco de dados o nome está com acentuação. Abaixo está o código que faz a requisição no banco e retorna o nome:

```
<?php
include("banco.php");
@$nome = $_POST["nome_aluno_busca"];
$sql = "SELECT codigo, nome FROM Aluno where nome like '%$nome%' order by nome;";
$result = mysql_query($sql, $conexao) or die (mysql_error());
$i = "0";
$i = mysql_num_rows($result);
echo "<div id=lista align=center>";
if ($i>0){
while ($linha = mysql_fetch_array ($result)) {
$codigo = $linha["codigo"];
$nome_aluno = $linha["nome"];
echo "<font color='red'><b>$codigo</b></font> - $nome_aluno<br><hr>";
}
}
echo "</div>";
?>
```

Comment: Vou deixar o link de um [artigo obrigatório do Joel Spolsky](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/) sobre o assunto. Achei [uma tradução pt-BR](https://medium.com/@sestrem/o-m%C3%ADnimo-que-todo-desenvolvedor-deve-saber-sobre-unicode-e-character-sets-789a4229ecf5) para algum interessado.

Answer (score -2):

Tente utilizar o seguinte bloco de código antes de imprimir a String

`utf8_encode($variavel_contendo_string)`

Answer (score -2):

Normalize seu banco de dados para UTF8.